# Manipulated Probability Question based on number i yielded after rolling

Tags: probability

(a) A six-sided die is manipulated in such a way that the face with the number i has
probability proportional to i. Find the probability that the die will produce an
even number if it is rolled once.
(b) An n-sided die is manipulated in such a way that the face with the number i has
probability proportional to i. Find the probability that the die will produce an
even number if it is rolled once.

What is meant by "proportional to i" here? No clue on how to determine (b). Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hint: $~\displaystyle \sum_{a=1}^n a = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$

Answer (score 3):

It means that there is some constant $k$ such that the probabilities of rolling $1$, $2$, $3$, etc. are $k$, $2k$, $3k$ etc. respectively.  Your next step might be to figure out what $k$ is.

Comment: Below is a solution I crafted, but it makes no sense as I had expected 1/2, 1/4, and 1/6 for the probabilities for the even numbers: The probability of each face with the number i can be represented as P(i) = i / (1+2+3+4+5+6) = i / 21. The probability of an even number is determined by summing up the probabilities of rolling the even faces {2, 4, 6}. Therefore:

P(even) = P(2) + P(4) + P(6) = 1/21(2 + 4 + 6) = 2/21 + 4/21 + 6/21 = 12/21 = 4/7

Comment: @user1279929: your expected probabilities are [inversely proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Inverse_proportionality) to the die face, not proportional. In your crafted solution, the probabilities are proportional.